# Error handling page is not displayed in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, error-handling

I followed a Flask tutorial and I am wanting to use error handling 404 and 500 to display custom webpages. I created 404.html and 500.html within the static/templates folder.

When I try to enter a wrong url such as 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/wfefef', I just get a blank page and a console error: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jul/2021 14:35:12] "GET /wfefef HTTP/1.1" 404 instead of giving me the custom html pages to handle such errors. What am I doing wrong?

Folder structure image:
[image]
-

The code for **app.py** is as follows:

```
import os
import pickle
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from ocr import ocr_processing
import werkzeug


UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER = '/static/uploads/'
ALLOWED_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
app.secret_key = ''
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1024 * 1024
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found_error(error):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404


@app.errorhandler(werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException)
def internal_error(error):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

**404.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {%block content %}
<h1>File Not Found</h1>
<p><a href="{{ url_for('upload') }}">Back</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

I have a similar code for 500 error

Comment: You need to put your 404.html and 500.html in templates folder not static/templates folder.

Comment: Even after putting them in templates folder, they still seem to not work @charchit

Comment: I have also uploaded an image of the folder structure. It's no more in the static folder. @charchit

Comment: Are other pages rendering in your app? Where is your app.py?

Comment: Yes, other pages are working fine. App.py is within the main directory itself. @charchit

Comment: I tried adding error pages to my project and they were working fine. I don't know what is the error in your case. Can you link a github repo to the code and share it here. Or if you want it to be private, contact me on discord `charchit#8198`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make you app on flask with `MVC` pattern. Create structure like that

```
| -- app
      | -- main
           | -- __init__.py
           | -- errors.py
           | -- views.py
      | -- templates
           | -- errors
                | -- 403.html
                | -- 404.html
                | -- 500.html
```

`__init__.py` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from flask import Blueprint
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
from . import views
```

`error.py` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from . import main
from flask import render_template


@main.app_errorhandler(404)
def page_404(e):
    return render_template('errors/404.html'), 404


@main.app_errorhandler(500)
def page_500(e):
    return render_template('errors/500.html'), 500


@main.app_errorhandler(403)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('errors/403.html'), 403
```

`views.py` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from . import errors  # it is important

@main.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```